# how to check open ports of bunch of website at once with nmap/linux?

Tags: linux, pipe, nmap

I want to use nmap in such a way that I could check bunch of server's port at once for checking whether their particular port is open or not?
right now I have 10 ip addresses but in future this could be more .
I know the very basic command in linux like cat/nano/piping
but I don't know how can I feed to nmap the list of my servers to open them one by one and return the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you have a file named "server_ips" with the IPs listed as such:

```
1.2.3.4
2.3.4.5
3.4.5.6
4.5.6.7
etc...
```

Then you could do the following:

```
$ cat server_ips | xargs nmap <nmap_options>
```

Comment: You can also use the -iL <inputfilename> option which accepts a file containing one IP/hostname/netblock per line.

Answer (score 0):

Write a target list of IPs or domains in a file, then

```
nmap -iL targetfile
```

This way nmap will take care of optimization and performance.